# Bulk insert to GridFS in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulkinsert, gridfs

Is it possible? If so then how?

Currently I'm inserting strings >16MB into GridFS one-by-one, but its very slow when dealing not with 1 string, but with thousands. I tried to check documentation, but didn't find a single line about bulk insert to GridFS storage, not just simple collection.

I'm using PyMongo for communication with MongoDB.

Comment: I would recommend not using gridfs for storage, but what have you tried? and why is gridfs a requirement?

Comment: Limit on 16MB per document is not letting me use basic collections. Splitting files is even more complicated thing since I want it to work fast without additional work with concatenation (basicly mongodb was supposed to be used get rid of this task + speed).

Comment: I fail to see why not just put the files in a static storage. What's the content of those strings? Why do they need to be in the database and not in a static storage?

Comment: It needs to be accessible fast in-memory (thats why MongoDB).

Comment: I guess you could thread and insert multiple records at once.

Comment: I thought about that, but Python is not multithreaded (multiprocessing is possible, but its not really multithreading replacement). :( Looking into Sharding now.

Comment: for IO multithreading is possible and doesn't block as much as you'd think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read and researched all the answers but unfortunately they didn't fulfill my requirements. The data that I was needed to use for specifying _id of jsons in GridFS was actually stored inside of JSON itself. It sounds like worst idea ever including redundancy and etc, but unfortunately its requirement.
What I did is I wrote insert thread for multiprocessing insertion to GridFS and inserted all the data with several threads (2 GridFS threads was enough to get proper performance).

Answer (score 1):

If you have them as files, sth like

```
for $LETTER in {a..z}
do
  ( find /path/to/basedir -iname "$LETTER*" -exec mongofiles -d yourGrid '{}' \; &)
done
```

should give you 26 threads pushing the data into MonoDB.

When finished, rename the yourGrid.fs collection according to your needs.

To make sure nothing gets broken, you should either run this command inside the screen utility or detach it from your terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately I have all them in one single file. Each line is single JSON.

Comment: Easy task: `LINES=\`wc -l yourbig.json\` split -l $(( $LINES / 26)) yourbig.json` and change the original script: `-iname "x$LETTER*"`

Comment: Seems like this way I won't be able to specify my own _id for GridFS files. But, guess, multiprocessing is the only way. I wish there was way to insert >16MB json in collection and backend did everything for chunking on its own + provided api for complete json select.

Comment: Well, if you need and own id, think of wether it can go to the metadata ;)

Answer (score 0):

That 16MB document size limit is also the limit in terms of bulk inserts to the database (see [request size limits](https://github.com/10gen/specifications/blob/master/source/driver-bulk-update.rst#request-size-limits) in the driver spec).  The bulk insert methods for documents are generally just batching things up into chunks (essentially giant arrays of documents) and sending them to the database.  You can try that out manually by creating a large array of documents and [doing an insert](https://github.com/comerford/mongodb-scripts/blob/master/crud.js#L57) yourself in the shell, but the upper bound will still be there.

When using GridFS, the chunk size which is used to split up the file being stored is 255/256k (at 255k by default since [this 2.4.10 change](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13331) and associated driver changes) so you could in theory fit ~64 chunks in a single message to the server but determining how to recover from failure might be tricky.  You can also configure that chunk size, which might be a better option, see the [pymongo reference](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/gridfs/grid_file.html) on chunkSize, but again you will need to stay under the 16MB limit.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about bulk insert limit. But still, I'm fine if there's a process of chunking. The problem is to do 1000 insertions in bulk insert or 1000 one-row inserts. I can do bulk insert to collection, but why can't I do bulk into GridFS. Even if its gonna be chunk'd before/after process, I still want to use speed advantage of bulk insert (multi-insert) over sending crazy amounts of single inserts. By default it was like that - collection includes 4 properties, one of which is json file which can easily exceed 16MB. So store json in gridFS and insert its key to collection instead.

Comment: So if I want to insert 1000 rows, I have to do 1000 json inserts into gridFS and after that insert 1000 rows in collection. One-row inserts are slow when number of rows growth to 10000 rows or even 100000, so inserting in one single bulk query would be the best option, but for gridFS I don't see such option at all, while it presents for collection somehow, not even talking about chunking. The question is how to do "multi-insert" to avoid resource and time waste. Btw, your link to driver spec is not working (private repo?).